# Turn mathematical equations (dtype is object) into a number python

Tags: python, regex, function, pandas, calculated-columns

So I have a column that is an object for dtype. The data looks like the following:

```
NaN
1*5+4
1*5+3.25
2*5+3.25
4.25
0
2*5+2.5
```

The desired output would be:

```
*blank or 0 for NaN*
9
8.25
13.25
4.25
0
12.5
```

I have tried using eval() and pd.eval() but was unsuccessful. I got the following errors, "TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object" and "AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'", respectively. Any functions that could perform this? Or do I need to perform actions on the column before calculating?

Comment: convert into `str` first before passing to `eval()`? It's hard to say without your actual code. You can edit in some [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I had tried converting it to a string first but didn't work. The fillna(0) solved my problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. Call `.fillna(0)` if you want to convert missing values to zero:

```
df[0].apply(pd.eval)

#0      NaN
#1     9.00
#2     8.25
#3    13.25
#4     4.25
#5     0.00
#6    12.50
#Name: 0, dtype: float64
```